# Undefined index: meta_h1 оно все работает и почему то выходит ошибка?

Tags: php, opencart

```
Notice: Undefined index: meta_h1 in /home/administrator/system/storage
/modification/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 233
```

Если убираю

```
if ($product_info['meta_h1']) {
                $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['meta_h1'];
            } else {
                $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];
            }
```

То пропадают все имена товаров и др вещи
А так все работает но ошибка висит почему то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
if ( !empty($product_info['meta_h1']) ) {
  $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['meta_h1'];
} else {
  $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];
}
```